# QT read XML file with DOM

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read an XML file and to store the elements into a QList of objects. Below is a part of the code that i have written. When i read it gets nothing to store. On console all that outputs is " "; 
What i am not doing well?

XML content

```
<Cars>
   <Car>
     <Owner>
       <FirstName> John <FirstName/>
       <LastName> Smith <LastName/>
       <Address> Canada <Address/>
     <Owner/>
   <Car/>
........More data
........More cars
<Cars/>
```

xml reading code

```
class Owner
{
private:
    QString firstName;
    QString lastName;
    QString address;
public:
    Owner();
    Owner(QString fName, QString lName, QString addr);
    QString getFirstName()const;
    QString getLastName() const;
    QString getAddress() const;
    void setFirstName(QString fName);
    void setLastName(QString lName);
    void setAddress(QString addr);
};

class Vehicle
{
private:
    Owner newOwner;
    QList<Verification> newVerification;
    Registration newRegistration;
    GeneralData newGeneralData;
    Equipment newEquipment;
    Characteristics newCharacteristics;

public:

    Vehicle();
    Owner getOwner() const;
    QList<Verification> getVerifications() const;
    int getVerificationsNumber() const;
    Registration getRegistration() const;
    GeneralData getGeneralData() const;
    Equipment getEquipment() const;
    Characteristics getCharacteristics() const;
    void setOwner(Owner owner);
    void setVerification(QList<Verification> ver);
    void setRegistration(Registration reg);
    void setGeneralData(GeneralData genData);
    void setEquipment(Equipment equipment);
    void setCharacteristics(Characteristics characteristics);
};


QList<Vehicle> readXML(QString fileName){
    QList<Vehicle> vehiclesList;
    QDomDocument document;
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << "Failed to open file";
    } else {
        if(!document.setContent(&file)){
            qDebug() << "Failed to load document";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Finished";
        }
        file.close();
    }

    QDomElement root = document.firstChildElement();
    QDomNodeList carElements = root.elementsByTagName("Car");
    for(int i = 0; i < carElements.count(); i++){
        //Car
        //****************************************************************
        //****************************************************************
        QDomNode carNode = carElements.at(i);

        //Owner
        //****************************************************************
        QDomElement ownerElement = carNode.firstChildElement("Owner");

        //FirstName
        QDomElement fNameElement = ownerElement.firstChildElement("FirstName");
        QString fName = fNameElement.text();
        qDebug() << fName; // it outputs " "


        //LastName
        QDomElement lNameElement = fNameElement.nextSiblingElement("LastName");
        QString lName = lNameElement.text();
        qDebug() << lName; // it outputs " "

        //Address
        QDomElement addressElement = lNameElement.nextSiblingElement("Address");
        QString address = addressElement.text();
        qDebug() << address; // it outputs " "

        //create owner object
        Owner newOwner;
        newOwner.setFirstName(fName);
        newOwner.setLastName(lName);
        newOwner.setAddress(address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it stop in the debugger?

Comment: You appear to have zero error checking in your code.  Beware that QT doesn't believe in using exceptions, and the QtXML certainly used be (and likely still is) full of places where you can get constructed objects back with error conditions.  You might find using a XML DOM parser with XPATH support makes like a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML sample is not properly formed:

```
<FirstName> John <FirstName/>
```

Should instead be:

```
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
```

[See more here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology)